# messagebox to show many variables in a list

Tags: c#

How to show all the list (how to use the messagebox to show the numbers under each other )

```
 List<int> numbers =new List<int>();
                numbers.Add(2);
                numbers.Add(4);
                numbers.Add(6);
                numbers.Add(8);
```

Comment: Is this just a c# question?  You've tagged 4 different languages.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Please show your efforts, along with their results.

Comment: sorry iam beginner in c#  i just started to learn it yesterday   i tried to do lots of things but failed to achieve my goal and i searched  about it but i cant find what i want so i asked here ....                          this is one  of my My attempts so u can tell me why it is wrong                                                 MessageBox.Show((numbers[0] \nnumbers[1] \nnumbers[2] \nnumbers[3]) .ToString());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to insert a newline between each number.

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, numbers));
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/vehpU35.png]

The resulting string displayed is: `"2\r\n4\r\n6\r\n8"`

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhakem You can mark this as the answer by clicking the check mark next to this post.